# Aspect ratio issue with iPad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I have added a big image in center of screen.I have given following constraints to the image.

- Center horizontal
- Top space
- Aspect ratio to self 
  -Aspect ratio to superview

I have added a view on top of that image having constrants

- Leading space from view
- top space from view
- Aspect ratio from self
- Aspect ratio from superview

I want my view to be on same place as it is on the 5s so it should be same place on image as on iPad.
I have made a logic like this

```
    float aspect_ratio_top=157.0/568.0;
    float aspect_ratio_width=81.0/320.0;

    float constant_top=self.view.frame.size.height*aspect_ratio_top;
    float constant_leading=self.view.frame.size.width*aspect_ratio_width;

    self.nslc_mainFrame_top.constant=constant_top;
    self.nslc_mainFrame_leading.constant=constant_leading;
```

Here 157.0 is value of constraint from top & 568.0 is iPhone5 height.
Here 81.0 is value of constraint from left & 320.0 is iPhone5 width.

This works great upto iPhone6 plus but on iPad width constraint value is not correct.I need to add more value to fit the width constraint.Please tell me the solution ?

Answer (score -1):

u can set equal width to superview and set multiplier (like 0.9 or 0.75) so view(imageView)width will set s per superview. if superview 100 and multiplier is 0.75 then imageView width will 75.

u can also set different multiplier for iPhone & iPad

Comment: But in this way i will not be same height & width ratio for all devices.I wan to know what's wrong with my logic.Why it fail on iPad i know height/width ratio of iPad is deferent from all other devices.